# Javascript and CSS Not Linking Properly to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to link my JavaScript file to my HTML file in Visual Studio Code, and I am getting a 404.

This problem doesn't happen for just JavaScript; my CSS external link also stopped working.

**General Info**

I am using Visual Studio Code. Within it, I am using Flask.

**JS File Info**

forecast.js file under /javascript/forecast.js

Inside my HTML, I have `<script src="/javascript/forecast.js"></script>` just before the closing **body** tag.
When I hover over the src

[image: Follow link]

link in VSCode, and click "Follow Link", it takes me to the correct file. So I don't think the issue is there. But when I run the Flask project, I get a `127.0.0.1 - - [08/Aug/2022 11:27:22] "GET /javascript/forecast.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -` error in the terminal. The website still runs, but no js is applied.

**CSS File Info**

This one is slightly different. I believe this is some sort of compiling error. I haven't ever had to deal with this problem before... my CSS used to work just fine, but one day it started acting up. In my HTML file, I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">`. Again, when I hover over the link and click "Follow link", it takes me to the correct css file. And in styles.css I have tons of styles. Now these two link fine, and the webpage loads properly.

However, for some reason, if I remove anything inside styles.css, the webpage runs the exact same with no changes. I don't have the CSS anywhere else, so somehow the website is taking a previous version of the CSS file and only using that, instead of the newest version. This is problematic, because I am unable to update any of my CSS... as it just looks for the non-updated version.

On top of this, if I remove the `<link>` to the css, the page stops functioning. I don't know if this is some strange compiling error, but not sure how to fix it.

I have checked numerous stack overflow pages on both issues, and none of them help. Both inline JS and CSS work, but every time I try external, it doesn't function. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if more details are required.

**Editing my Edit**

Thank you for explaining. I've tried to use some of the answers in that question, but they did not end up helping. Adding a static URL path, a static folder, and a template folder didn't end up changing anything. I'm pretty confused on the first answer (that was also the right answer), as I don't see how I can serve my HTML, CSS, and JS file at the same time in one import, especially when they are in different directories.

Comment: You might try using `./` before your file references as in `src="./javascript/forecast.js"`.  Easy to try anyway.

Comment: "My issue is not about serving static files in Flask"—that's exactly what it is. You need to serve your JavaScript and CSS files as static files, and the `src` value you use must point to whatever path they're available on. That's not necessarily the same relative path as on the local filesystem (in fact it probably isn't).